# Segmentation fault - printf value from pointer to pointer

Tags: c++, c, struct

I am trying to find the problem here - in this function:

```
void PrintDic(dictionary **head)
    {
        dictionary *current = *head;
        if(current->nexdic==NULL)
            printf("empty dictionary\n");
        else
        {
            while(current->nexdic!=NULL)
            {
                int i;
                for(i=0;i<1; i++)
                    printf("%s\n",current->word);
                current=current->nexdic;
            }
        }
    }
```

In Visual Studio it works, but in Linux it always gives me a segmentation fault.

The struct:

```
struct dictionary
{
    char word[MAXLETTERS];
    char** year;
    int countyear;
    char** synonyms;
    int countsyn;
    char** def;
    int countdef;
    struct dictionary*nexdic;

};
```

The add function: (Insert the values to the struct and find place in lexicographic way to add the struct = linked list!)

```
void Add(char* word, char * year,int countyear, char*syn, int countsyn, char* def,int countdef, dictionary** head)
{
    dictionary*next;
    //add new entry
    dictionary*newentry=(dictionary*)malloc(sizeof(dictionary));
    if(CheckNull(newentry)==1)
        exit(1);
    int i;
    char *index;
    //insert word
    strcpy(newentry->word,word);
    //insert year
    char **toyear=(char **)malloc((countyear+1)*sizeof(char*));
    index=year;
    for(i=0;i<=countyear; i++)
    {
        toyear[i]=index;
        index=NextString(index);
    }
    newentry->year=toyear;
    //insert syn 
    index=syn;
    char **tosyn=(char **)malloc((countsyn+1)*sizeof(char*));
    for(i=0;i<=countsyn; i++)
    {
        tosyn[i]=index;
        index=NextString(index);
    }
    newentry->synonyms=tosyn;
    //insert definition
    index=def;
    char **todef=(char **)malloc((countdef+1)*sizeof(char*));
    for(i=0;i<=countdef; i++)
    {
        todef[i]=index;
        index=NextString(index);
    }
    newentry->def=todef;
    //set counts
    newentry->countyear=countyear+1;
    newentry->countsyn=countsyn+1;
    newentry->countdef=countdef+1;
    next=FindPlace(newentry->word,*head);
    if(next==NULL)
    {
        if(*head==NULL)
            newentry->nexdic=NULL;
        else
        {
            newentry->nexdic=*head;
        }
        *head=newentry;
    }
    else
    {
        newentry->nexdic=next->nexdic;
        next->nexdic=newentry;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, you don't show how your structure gets populated, so you either have a null pointer or are indexing an array out-of-bounds.  Time to learn how to use the debugger.

Comment: It's probably because `current->def[i]` points to a freed item on the system that segfaults.

Comment: Verify how are you initializing your structure before it is being used. A probably reason that in VS it works and in linux not, can be that VS (specially in Debug version) initializes your `current->nexdic`with NULL (and you got `current->nexdic==NULL` true) and in linux it goes to `else`, causing the crash

Comment: You check for `current->nextdic` being `NULL` but you never check whether `current` (ie., `*head`) is `NULL`.  We can't tell from the posted code whether that's something that needs to be checked or not.  In either case, it seems to be a logic error to print stuff pointed to by `current` based on whether or not `current->nextdic` is a valid pointer (the last item pointed to by `nextdic` wouldn't be printed).

Comment: Maybe in unposted `NextString()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem with code below.

In while loop, your `current` become `current->nexic`, this could not `NULL`. For next iteration while try to access your `current` `(current->nexdic`) which is `NULL` and hence segment fault.

```
    while(current->nexdic!=NULL)
    {
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<current->countdef; i++)
            printf("%s\n",current->def[i]);
        current=current->nexdic;
    }
```

I don't know your logic of program, but you can check `while(current != NULL)` instead of `current->nexdic`

Comment: added another function

Comment: I don't believe this answer makes sense, given the code that was posted. The `while` loop is not entered unless the program has already confirmed that both `current` and `current->nexdic` are not NULL. The logic of the `while` loop seems to be sound.

Comment: In your `Add` function where you perform `strcpy(newentry->word, word)`, I am assuming this is what gets passed to `PrintDic`, could `newentry->word` be getting overrun (don't forget '\0')?

Answer (score 0):

This code seems to work (tested on Mac OS X 10.9.1 with GCC 4.8.2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

enum { MAXLETTERS = 32 };

typedef struct dictionary
{
    char word[MAXLETTERS];
    char **year;
    char **synonyms;
    char **def;
    int countyear;
    int countsyn;
    int countdef;
    struct dictionary *nexdic;
} dictionary;

static void PrintDic(dictionary **head)
{
    dictionary *current = *head;
    while (current != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s\n", current->word);
        current = current->nexdic;
    }
}

static int CheckNull(dictionary *dict)
{
    return dict == 0;
}

static char *NextString(char *str)
{
    return strchr(str, ',');
}

static dictionary *FindPlace(char *word, dictionary *head)
{
    printf("FP: (%p) [%s]\n", (void *)head, word);
    dictionary *ohead = 0;
    while (head != 0 && printf("HW: (%p) [%s]\n", head, head->word) > 0 && strcmp(head->word, word) < 0)
    {
        ohead = head;
        head = head->nexdic;
    }
    printf("FP: (%p)\n", (void *)ohead);
    return ohead;
}

static void Add(char *word, char *year, int countyear, char *syn, int countsyn,
                char *def, int countdef, dictionary **head)
{
    // Create new entry
    // add new entry
    dictionary *newentry = (dictionary *)malloc(sizeof(dictionary));
    if (CheckNull(newentry) == 1)
        exit(1);
    int i;
    char *index;
    // insert word
    strcpy(newentry->word, word);
    // insert year
    char **toyear = (char **)malloc((countyear + 1) * sizeof(char *));
    index = year;
    for (i = 0; i <= countyear; i++)
    {
        toyear[i] = index;
        index = NextString(index);
    }
    newentry->year = toyear;
    // insert syn
    index = syn;
    char **tosyn = (char **)malloc((countsyn + 1) * sizeof(char *));
    for (i = 0; i <= countsyn; i++)
    {
        tosyn[i] = index;
        index = NextString(index);
    }
    newentry->synonyms = tosyn;
    // insert definition
    index = def;
    char **todef = (char **)malloc((countdef + 1) * sizeof(char *));
    for (i = 0; i <= countdef; i++)
    {
        todef[i] = index;
        index = NextString(index);
    }
    newentry->def = todef;
    // set counts
    newentry->countyear = countyear + 1;
    newentry->countsyn = countsyn + 1;
    newentry->countdef = countdef + 1;

    // Insert new entry in correct place
    dictionary *next = FindPlace(newentry->word, *head);
    printf("Next = %p; head = %p\n", (void *)next, (void *)*head);
    if (next == NULL)
    {
        printf("-1-\n");
        newentry->nexdic = *head;
        *head = newentry;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("-2-\n");
        newentry->nexdic = next->nexdic;
        next->nexdic = newentry;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    char line[4096];
    dictionary *head = 0;
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin) != 0)
    {
        size_t offset = 0;
        char word[4096];
        int nchars;
        line[strlen(line)-1] = '\0';
        printf("Line: [%s]\n", line);
        while (sscanf(line + offset, "%s%n", word, &nchars) == 1)
        {
            printf("Word: [%s]\n", word);
            char *years = "1990,1999";
            char *syns = "a,z";
            char *defs = "definition1,definition2";
            printf("Old Head = %p\n", head);
            Add(word, years, 2, syns, 2, defs, 2, &head);
            PrintDic(&head);
            printf("New Head = %p\n", head);
            offset += nchars;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Apart from writing the missing functions like `FindPlace()`, `CheckNull()` and `NextString()` (and a test driver, `main()`), and defining that `FindPlace()` returns NULL when the new node should be at the head of the list and otherwise the new node should be inserted immediately after the node pointer that is returned, the main changes were to the code that handles 'insert at head' which was more complex than it needed to be.  There was a funny one-cycle `for` loop in `PrintDic()` which is no more.  You made the process uncomfortable for us by including the years, synonyms and definitions information, which was probably not material to the problem at hand.  The driver does about the simplest thing possible with those.  Note that it does not split the strings passed into `Add()`, so the first year entry prints everything, the second prints all but the first, and so on, and similarly for the synonyms and definitions.  In each case, the list items are separated by commas.

There's swathes of debug printing code in place; you're welcome to remove it.

Sample output:

```
ggg
Line: [ggg]
Word: [ggg]
Old Head = 0x0
FP: (0x0) [ggg]
FP: (0x0)
Next = 0x0; head = 0x0
-1-
ggg
New Head = 0x7f848bc038b0
fff
Line: [fff]
Word: [fff]
Old Head = 0x7f848bc038b0
FP: (0x7f848bc038b0) [fff]
HW: (0x7f848bc038b0) [ggg]
FP: (0x0)
Next = 0x0; head = 0x7f848bc038b0
-1-
fff
ggg
New Head = 0x7f848bc03960
ccc
Line: [ccc]
Word: [ccc]
Old Head = 0x7f848bc03960
FP: (0x7f848bc03960) [ccc]
HW: (0x7f848bc03960) [fff]
FP: (0x0)
Next = 0x0; head = 0x7f848bc03960
-1-
ccc
fff
ggg
New Head = 0x7f848bd00000
ddd
Line: [ddd]
Word: [ddd]
Old Head = 0x7f848bd00000
FP: (0x7f848bd00000) [ddd]
HW: (0x7f848bd00000) [ccc]
HW: (0x7f848bc03960) [fff]
FP: (0x7f848bd00000)
Next = 0x7f848bd00000; head = 0x7f848bd00000
-2-
ccc
ddd
fff
ggg
New Head = 0x7f848bd00000
eee
Line: [eee]
Word: [eee]
Old Head = 0x7f848bd00000
FP: (0x7f848bd00000) [eee]
HW: (0x7f848bd00000) [ccc]
HW: (0x7f848be00000) [ddd]
HW: (0x7f848bc03960) [fff]
FP: (0x7f848be00000)
Next = 0x7f848be00000; head = 0x7f848bd00000
-2-
ccc
ddd
eee
fff
ggg
New Head = 0x7f848bd00000
aaa
Line: [aaa]
Word: [aaa]
Old Head = 0x7f848bd00000
FP: (0x7f848bd00000) [aaa]
HW: (0x7f848bd00000) [ccc]
FP: (0x0)
Next = 0x0; head = 0x7f848bd00000
-1-
aaa
ccc
ddd
eee
fff
ggg
New Head = 0x7f848be000b0
bbb
Line: [bbb]
Word: [bbb]
Old Head = 0x7f848be000b0
FP: (0x7f848be000b0) [bbb]
HW: (0x7f848be000b0) [aaa]
HW: (0x7f848bd00000) [ccc]
FP: (0x7f848be000b0)
Next = 0x7f848be000b0; head = 0x7f848be000b0
-2-
aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd
eee
fff
ggg
New Head = 0x7f848be000b0
zzz 
Line: [zzz]
Word: [zzz]
Old Head = 0x7f848be000b0
FP: (0x7f848be000b0) [zzz]
HW: (0x7f848be000b0) [aaa]
HW: (0x7f848bc03a10) [bbb]
HW: (0x7f848bd00000) [ccc]
HW: (0x7f848be00000) [ddd]
HW: (0x7f848bf00000) [eee]
HW: (0x7f848bc03960) [fff]
HW: (0x7f848bc038b0) [ggg]
FP: (0x7f848bc038b0)
Next = 0x7f848bc038b0; head = 0x7f848be000b0
-2-
aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd
eee
fff
ggg
zzz
New Head = 0x7f848be000b0
```